# Unable to mount USB_SAMSUNG in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: android, usb, ubuntu-14.04, mount, mtp

I really appreciate Ubuntu 14.04 and my Samsung Galaxy S3 mini (8200N).
However, I had strange issues when plugging in the phone and Ubuntu wasn't able to mount properly.
I want to share my experience with you, as it was a struggle for quite some time to me.
This will apply to phones other than the I8200N as well.

If I plugged in the phone in Ubuntu, I got the error message

```
Unable to mount MTP device USB_SAMSUNG
```

one to up to a hundred times. This was really annoying.
Sometimes Ubuntu "managed" to mount the phone, but it was empty.
There was a very rare chance, that Ubuntu really managed to mount it.

I searched for this problem, however the accepted solution was to add the device to `/lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules`.
In my case the device was already listed.

The next suggestion was to turn on USB debugging on the phone.
Since I use it for Android development, it has been turned on very early.
No solution either.

Answer (score 1):

The freak in my mind whispered: **Turn off USB debugging** and watch the phone burn.
Surprisingly this did the trick. Ubuntu can mount my phone now and I am able to synchronize data - finally.

Answer (score 0):

Try to plug into back USB port if you're on desktop. For me it seems like lack of power, I've tried to connect to "back" USB port and it helped.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I recommend to stop using MTP/PTP on Ubuntu 14.04:

While copying music from my laptop to a Samsung I8200N, the connection aborted. Both my internal device storage and the SD card have been wiped.

I'm a little bit "pissed off", as this deleted all pictures I have taken and stuff I downloaded to the device.